# quickly change permissions of all directories in $HOME while skipping all mounts

Tags: permissions, filesystems, find, mount

**In the case where the user home directory contains one or more NFS mount points, how can I skip these mounts and efficiently change directory permissions?**

I want to run `chmod o-rwx` on all non-mounted directories under a user's home directory.

I will be running the command as the root user because I'm doing this for all users on the system. (The NFS mounts have the `root_squash` mount option.)

Here is what I tried. However, it is not working as expected.

```
sudo find /home/myuser/ -mount -path ./Documents -prune -o -type d -exec chmod o-rwx {} \;
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/myuser/Documents': Operation not permitted
```

I want to avoid the error message. More importantly, the find command is taking a very long time to run. I believe that indicates it is descending into the mount points (which contain many directories and files).

**Another problem with my command is that I have to explicitly code for the locations to skip.** All users have Documents mounted, but some users have other NFS mounts of different names.

My goal is to automate the fixing of simple directory permission problems in a user account (i.e., `chmod o-rwx`). How can I do this in my situation?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-_002dxdev

Comment: @muru - I am already using the `-mount` option. Is that what you were suggesting? All you did was post a link, so I don't know what you intended me to see there.

Comment: -mount should be doing what you wanted, and the error listed is because Documents is itself is a mountpoint.  Are you *sure* that it's actually descending into the mountpoints?  You could run an echo instead of the chmod to check for certain.

Comment: You are using it, `-mount` prevents *descending into* mounted directories, so it will only exclude contents of `Documents`, not `Documents` itself.

Comment: @Egon - "Are you sure that it's actually descending into the mountpoints?" No. I will check. However, I want to avoid the error message of `Documents` itself, as well as to avoid explicitly listing all mount points in the command. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem with your prune is that it's trying to match `./Documents` literally against the full path including the base you provided (`/home/myuser/Documents`).  To do it on a larger scale you probably need to change the -path argument to `*/Documents` or `/home/*/Documents`.

Comment: @Egon - yes, you are exactly right about that. Changing that helps for part of the issues I raised in the question. I found mention of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595367/463994

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
find /home/$theuser -mount -maxdepth 1 ! -fstype nfs4 ! -fstype nfs -type d -exec chmod o-rwx {} \;
```

The negated `fstype` options solved one or two of my problems. The `-maxdepth 1` solved the other (speed).

It may be possible to combine the two `-fstype` options. If anyone knows, please edit this answer.